# Can I have multiple values in a DataValueField?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it possible to put multiple values in a DataValueField?

For example, with the following code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ixTeam" CssClass="ixTeam" runat="server" DataSourceID="dsixTeam" 
 DataValueField="TeamID" DataTextField="TeamName" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
```

Is it possible for me to put two values (e.g. `TeamID + "|" + TeamTypeID`) into the DataValueField?

Answer (score 15):

You can't combine two fields in `DataValueField`, but you can try couple of things.

1. You can build your SQL query with concatenation, (if you are getting the data from database)

SQL query:

```
Select (TeamID +"|"+ TeamTypeID) as CombinedTeam, .....`
```

and then set

```
DataFieldValue = "CombinedTeam"
```

Or

1. You can use LINQ query to create an anonymous type based on concatenation of two fields.

for example:

```
var query = from t in yourDataSource
            select new 
            {
                 CombinedTeam = t.TeamID + "|" + t.TeamTypeID,
            }
```

Then specify the data source for the drop down to the LINQ query, and specify the `DataFieldValue`

```
yourDropDownList.DataSource = query;
yourDropDownList.DataFieldValue = "CombinedTeam";
```

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is you cannot.

Instead, create a calculated column in your dataset which has `TeamID + '|' + TeamTypeID` for its expression (you can also do this when you fetch the data adding a formatted display column to your select query, assuming you are using a database), then bind on that column instead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done. Either format your data when retrieving from SQL server as following:

```
Select TeamID + ' | ' + TeamTypeID CombinedColumn
```

Now set the `DataValueField=CombinedColumn`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  CAST(TeamID AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' | ' + CAST(TeamTypeID AS VARCHAR(100)) as CombinedColumn, TeamID ,TeamTypeID FROM [tblName]
```

This works for me, rest are giving conversion to int errors.