# Bind Dropdown with two values in .net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I Want To bind my **dropdownlist** with two value using some separator just [like '-' or '/'] in .net 3.5.

```
 qry = "SELECT CityName, MasterState.StateName FROM MasterCity INNER JOIN "+
              "MasterState ON MasterCity.StateID = MasterState.StateID order by CityName";

DropCity.DataMember = "DeafultView";
//DropCity.DataTextField = "CityName";
//DropCity.DataValueField = "CityName";
DropCity.DataTextFormatString = "{0} - {1}";
DropCity.DataTextField = "CityName,StateName";
DropCity.DataSource = dt;
DropCity.DataBind();
DropCity.Items.Insert(0, "-Select-");**
```

I did it but it gives error

**DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'CityName,StateName'."}**

How can i do this?

Comment: Hi this post might help you. You can combine the two fields from your SQL query. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715412/multiple-value-in-datavaluefield-c-sharp-net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DropCity.DataTextField = "CityName,StateName";
```

`DataTextField` will look for column `CityName,StateName` and it doesn't exist.

May be you can change your query like this

```
qry = "SELECT CityName, CityName + '-' + MasterState.StateName as CityState
    FROM MasterCity INNER JOIN "+
          "MasterState ON MasterCity.StateID = MasterState.StateID order by CityName";

    DropCity.DataTextField = "CityState";
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it's possible to bind two things at once, although you can change your SQL query to return what you need.

Change:-

```
qry = "SELECT CityName, MasterState.StateName FROM MasterCity INNER JOIN "+
  "MasterState ON MasterCity.StateID = MasterState.StateID order by CityName";
```

To

```
qry = "SELECT CityName, MasterState.StateName, " + 
     "CityName + ' - ' + MasterState.StateName AS DDName " +
      " FROM MasterCity INNER JOIN "+
      "MasterState ON MasterCity.StateID = MasterState.StateID order by CityName";
```

Then change:-

```
DropCity.DataTextField = "CityName,StateName";
```

to :-

```
DropCity.DataTextField = "DDName";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this .. i have modified the quesry slightly. Hope it works.

```
qry = "SELECT CityName , CityName + "-" + MasterState.StateName as CityNState FROM
        MasterCity INNER JOIN MasterState ON MasterCity.StateID = MasterState.StateID order by
        CityName";

DropCity.DataMember = "DeafultView";
DropCity.DataTextField = "CityNState";
DropCity.DataSource = dt;
DropCity.DataBind();
DropCity.Items.Insert(0, "-Select-");
```